# How to get values using select2 in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have multiple select that contains options of languages and I want to get the values selected.
I tried that using by retrieve the value from the id but nothing shown in the console.

```
 $('#language').select2();

<select  id="language" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" data-toggle="select2"> 
     <option value="1">FR</option>
     <option value="1">Eng</option>
     <option value="1">Es</option>
       
</select>


var selectedValues = $('#language').val();
console.log(selectedValues);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
selectedValues = $('#language').val();
```

will give you the array of values of selected options.

Here is a demo:

```js
$('#language').select2().on('change', function(e) {
  var selectedValues = $('#language').val();
  console.log(selectedValues);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select id="language" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" data-toggle="select2">
  <option value="1">FR</option>
  <option value="2">Eng</option>
  <option value="3">Es</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
var selectedValues = $('#language').find(':selected').val();
console.log(selectedValues);
```